# How can I find the actual machine our Active Directory server is on?

Tags: active-directory

I know the name of the Domain, but I need to RDC to the actual computer to add someone and the sysadmins are on vacation.  Anyone know how I can figure out the IP for the DOMAIN?

Comment: why not run dsa.msc then connect to your domain?

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear enough, run this from your workstation it will automagically connect you to the correct domain.  You'll need to do a runas to get it to work correctly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The environment variable `%LOGONSERVER%` stores the name of the Domain Controller that authenticated your logon.

```
echo %LOGONSERVER%
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use this command from cmd prompt:

```
gpresult /R
```

Then look for this line in the output:

```
Group Policy was applied from: server.domain.com
```

Comment: Or run "set" and look for LOGONSERVER

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to RDC to it, you can just type in your DNS Domain Name.
For example, if you're in the example.com domain, you can RDC to "example.com" and get one of the Domain Controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly AD will be the same as your DNS server which you can find by typing:

ipconfig /all

Comment: This is not necessarily true at all.  Many places run bind, or use hosted DNS servers.  My recommendation would be to perform an NSLOOKUP on your AD domain.  That should give you an IP or list of IPs.  Then do an NSLOOKUP on those IPs.  There should be reverse records for DCs.  A reverse lookup of those IPs will return the DC name hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

From the command prompt you can also run "systeminfo" which will echo the Logon Server and other info.